# Symbols from packages bbding and utfsym make package wrapfig2 not working properly

Tags: fonts, symbols, size, wrapfig

I have the following code, trying to wrap an image with some sentences beginning with a symbol from packages `bbding` and `utfsym`. Probably the problem can occur using and other symbols packages.
If I use any symbol from `bbding` package or a symbol from `utfsym` package with `\large`, `\Large` etc commands then the package `wrapfig2` cannot "cut" the lines of text, and they overcame the image. Why this happens and how can we solve it?
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{utfsym,bbding,wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
            \vspace{-6mm}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\footnotesize Example image}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \usym{1F4D6} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \usym{1F4D7} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \usym{1F4E1} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    {\large \usym{1F4D6}} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \PencilRightDown \dotfill
    
    \dotfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are starting the paragraph in a group. Use `\leavevmode{\large ...` and `\leavevmode\PencilRightDown`.

Comment: Quick and efficient! @Ulrike Fisher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wrapfig has to change the shape of paragraphs at the begin of a paragraph.  This code fails if the begin is inside a group. (The bbding commands open a group without leaving vmode first). Use \leavevmode to start the paragraph:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{utfsym,bbding,wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
            \vspace{-6mm}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\footnotesize Example image}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \usym{1F4D6} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \usym{1F4D7} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \usym{1F4E1} This is a test sentence \dotfill \par
    
    \leavevmode{\large \usym{1F4D6}} This is a test sentence \dotfill
    
    \leavevmode\PencilRightDown \dotfill
    
    \dotfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mbox{...}` might be even better.